# How to resolve "Corresponding file not included in tsconfig.json" error in WebStorm?

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, webstorm, typescript-typings, tsconfig

I am using highland.js and have installed it with its type definition:

```
jq .dependencies package.json | grep highland
  "@types/highland": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/highland/-/highland-1.14.30.tgz",
  "highland": "^2.9.0",
```

I am using PhpStorm (which uses the WebStorm component for TypeScript).

When I typehint for:

```
Highland.Stream<any>
```

PhpStorm complains about the Stream:

```
Corresponding file not included in tsconfig.json
```

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Yet the go to declaration works and it jumps to `node_modules/@types/highland/index.d.ts:367`:

```
interface Stream<R> extends NodeJS.EventEmitter { ... }
```

I can compile the code fine with `tsc` without errors and it's working as expected. What is PhpStorm's / WebStorm's problem?

```
$ jq . tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "types": [
      "node",
      "mocha",
      "chai",
      "sinon"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/typings-custom/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I tried adding highland to `types` to no avail, and I have no idea what the error is telling me.

Comment: PhpStorm version? TypeScript compiler version?

Comment: @lena typescript 2.1, phpstorm2016.2

Comment: please try upgrading to 2016.3.1. TypeScript 2.1 is not supported in 2016.2

Comment: @lena Same problem with TypeScript 3.0.3 and PhpStorm 2018.2.2 for ts-jest but I've found that enabling the "TypeScript Language service" in project settings makes the problem go away, although I'm not sure why.

Comment: Phpstorm? I guess you mean Webstorm

Comment: @DiWang I mean both. PhpStorm includes the features of WebStorm.

Comment: Not a solution that's fun, but for me I saw I had an update to Intellij and then my same error went away

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue with Webstorm 2018. I closed and reopened Webstorm and, voilà: the red lines were gone! I just needed to refresh Webstorm I guess.  Since Webstorm and PHPStorm are both under the same umbrellas, maybe this will work for you as well.

Answer (score 7):

Just go to `File > Repair IDE` and works as well.

Comment: How have I never seen this 

Answer (score 3):

I needed to add `@types/node`

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^16.11.19",
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be caused by disabled Typescript language service.

Open    `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript`
Enable `Typescript language service`

Answer (score 0):

Updating Webstorm to the latest version fixed this issue for me.